# Folland's Proof of Alaoglu's Theorem, "topology of pointwise convergence"

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, compactness, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces

> **Theorem:** If $X$ is a normed vector space, the closed unit ball $B^* := \{ f \in X^* \, : \, \|f\| \le 1 \}$ in $X^*$ is compact in the weak$^*$ topology.
>
> *Proof:* For each $x \in X$, let $D_x := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \, : \, |z| \le \|x \| \}$ and $D:= \prod_{x \in X} D_x$, which is compact by Tychnoff's Theorem.
>
> The relative topologies that $B^*$ inherits from the product topology on $D$ and the weak $^*$ topology coincide with topology of pointwise convergence, **so it suffices to see that $B^*$ is closed...**

Why are the two topologies the same? This is how I would argue:

$D$ has the product topology, and $B^*$ has as a subspace, a topology generated by 
$$ \{ B^* \cap  \pi_x^{-1}(U_k) \, : \, U_k \text{ open in } D_x \}_{x \in X}$$ 
As a subspace of the weak$^*$ topology, $B^*$ also has another topology given by basis, 
\begin{align*}
 \{ B^* \cap x^{-1}(U_k) \, : \, U_k \text{ open in } \mathbb{C} \}_{x \in X} 
\end{align*} 
where $x \in X^{**}$ is an identification of $x \in X$. These two sets generate the same topology as $f \in B^* \Rightarrow f(x) \in D_x$, so $B^* \cap x^{-1}(U_k) = B^* \cap x^{-1}(U_k \cap D_x) = B^* \cap \pi_x^{-1}(\hat{U}_k)$ where $\hat{U}_k$ is an open set in $D_x$.

Comment: "The relative topologies […] coincide with […]" means that both relative topologies are the same, namely the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: Is there only one topology with the "topology of pointwise convergence", I don't remember the author defining the "topology of pointwise convergence".

Comment: If you have a set $S$ of functions $A \to B$, with $B$ a topological space, the topology of pointwise convergence on $S$ is the topology such that a filter $\mathscr{F}$ resp. net $(f_{\alpha})$ on $S$ converges to $f$ if and only if for every $a\in A$ the filter $\mathscr{F}(a)$ resp. the net $\bigl(f_{\alpha}(a)\bigr)$ converges to $f(a)$ in $B$. It's the subspace topology induced from $B^A$ (with the product topology) on $S$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so now what I don't see is why the weak$^*$ topology coincides with the "topology of pointwise convergence." Is my argument correct? It seems a bit long, or is there a faster way to see this.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I think the most transparent way is to look at a bigger picture. Consider the space $\mathscr{F}(X,\mathbb{C})$ of _all_ functions $X\to \mathbb{C}$. This is simply $\mathbb{C}^X$. And the product topology on $\mathbb{C}^X$ is the "topology of pointwise convergence". And clearly $X^{\ast} \subset \mathscr{F}(X,\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^X$. And the weak$^{\ast}$ topology on $X^{\ast}$ is just the subspace topology. And clearly $D \subset \mathbb{C}^X$, and the product topology on $D$ is the subspace topology.

Comment: And by the transitivity of initial topologies, the subspace topology on $B^{\ast}$ induced by either of $X^{\ast}$ or $D$ is just the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{C}^X$.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't see that the weak$^*$ topology is same as the subspace topology - but don't we have to prove this too? It seems like it is a similar argument...

Comment: One can put that in a broader context. If we have a vector space $E$ and a family $\mathscr{P}$ of seminorms on $E$, and a subspace $F \subset E$, then the family $\mathscr{P}\rvert_F = \{ p\rvert_F : p \in \mathscr{P}$ induces the subspace topology for the topology induced by $\mathscr{P}$ on $E$. Which is a one-line proof since $p\rvert_F^{-1}([0,\varepsilon)) = p^{-1}([0,\varepsilon)) \cap F$.

Answer (score 1):

Because a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: Sorry, my question was phrased really badly. I just wanted to know why the two topologies are the same.